# Posting the result of a radio button click use Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a script that posts the result of a radio button click using Ajax.

So far I have:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="DisableAd" value="0" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
    Radio
</label><br/>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="DisableAd" value="0" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
    Radio
</label>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.DisableAd').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var parameters = {
      'disAd': $('input[name="DisableAd"]').val(),
    };
    if (parameters == 0) {
      parameters = 0;
    } else {
      parameters = 1;
    }

    console.log('Posting: ', parameters);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'disableAd.php',
      data: parameters,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        //  ... do something with the data...
        console.log('Ad disabled', data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The above code does not work but I can't see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using selector `".DisableAd"` for your click handler but you do not have a class with that name. Instead use `$('[name="DisableAd"]')`. 
I also changed the radio values so you can see the reflected changes with the `parameters` object `disAd` property assignment - which i changed to `$(this).val()` Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="DisableAd"]').click(function() {
    //event.preventDefault();

    var parameters = {
      'disAd': $(this).val(), // changed this as well so you can retrieve selected radio value
    };
    
    if (parameters.disAd == 0) {
      parameters = 0;
    } else {
      parameters = 1;
    }

    console.log('Posting: ', parameters);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'disableAd.php',
      data: parameters,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        //  ... do something with the data...
        console.log('Ad disabled', data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="DisableAd" value="0" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
Radio</label><br/>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="DisableAd" value="1" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
Radio</label>
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for looking at the issue and providing the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You have used class selector  $('.DisableAd').click(function() ....

But you haven't declared the class attribute in radio button input type element.

Declare a class in input type element as follows:

`<input type="radio" class="DisableAd" name="DisableAd" value="0" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
Radio</label><br/>
<label>
<input type="radio" class="DisableAd" name="DisableAd" value="0" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
Radio</label>`

It will work! :)